# Work with function references

Tags: c++, function, boost, reference, bind

I have another one question about functions reference.
For example, I have such definition:

```
typedef boost::function<bool (Entity &handle)> behaviorRef;
std::map< std::string, ptr_vector<behaviorRef> > eventAssociation;
```

The first question is: how to insert values into such map object?

I tried:

```
eventAssociation.insert(std::pair< std::string, ptr_vector<behaviorRef> >(eventType, ptr_vector<behaviorRef>(callback)));
```

But the error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘boost::ptr_vector<boost::function<bool(Entity&)> >::push_back(Entity::behaviorRef&)’
```

And I undersatnd it, but can't make workable code.

The second question is how to call such functions?
For example, I have one object of **behaviorRef**, how to call it with **boost::bind** with passing my own values?

Comment: As a tip, you can use `std::make_pair()` instead of constructing the pair directly; this lets you avoid having to write out the pair's template parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PART 1**

There's no need to use a `ptr_vector`. `boost::function` has value semantics, so can be stored in a standard container. So the following should work:

```
typedef boost::function<bool (Entity &handle)> behaviorRef;
std::map< std::string, std::vector<behaviorRef> > eventAssociation;

eventAssociation.insert(std::make_pair(eventType, vector<behaviorRef>(1, callback)));
```

Note the two arguments to the `vector` constructor.

If you did need a `ptr_vector` (because you were using a noncopyable type), you'd need something like the following, since `ptr_vector` doesn't have a constructor that populates the vector:

```
ptr_vector<behaviorRef> behaviours;
behaviours.push_back(new behaviourRef(callback));
eventAssociation.insert(std::make_pair(eventType, behaviours));
```

**PART 2**

There's no need to use `boost::bind` for calling the function (although you can use it to make it in the first place). The syntax for calling it is the same as for a normal function:

```
behaviourRef behaviour;
Entity entity;
bool result = behaviour(entity);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't understand why do you passing two argmuments to the std::vector?

Comment: @Ockonal: The first argument is the size of the vector (i.e., the number of object it initially holds), the second one is an object that will be used to copy-construct the initially created objects. For example: `vector<Foo>(10, some_foo)` creates a vector containing 10 clones of some_foo

Answer (score 3):

**First question:**

`ptr_vector<Foo>` contains pointers to Foo. So if you need to use `ptr_vector` (maybe because your function objects are expensive to copy), you have to push_back pointers to behaviorRef.

**Second question, part one:**

A behaviorRef is called with the same syntax than a `bool(Entity&)` function:

```
// Somehow get an Entity and a behaviorRef
Entity some_entity = ...;
behaviorRef some_behavior = ...;

// Call the behaviorRef
bool result = some_behavior(some_entity);
```

**Second question, part two:**

A behaviorRef can be used with boost::bind in the same way than another function object:

```
// Somehow get an Entity and a behaviorRef
Entity some_entity = ...;
behaviorRef some_behavior = ...;

// Make a new function object, bound to some_entity
boost::function<bool()> bound_behavior = boost::bind(some_behavior, some_entity);

// Call the bound function.
bool result = bound_behavior();
```

Comment: Your answer for second question is great, thank you! It's a pity that I can't mark two answers.